# TaskCreationOptions for an async Task Method

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library, task, async-await, c#-5.0

I have a method returning an async Task. I wish to call this but I'd like to customise the TaskCreationOptions sent to it, I'm trying to work out best practise for this, or how I should modify my approach?

Sample..

```
void Main(){        
    _runTask=Test(); // I wish to provide creation options here, ie LongRunning, and possibly also a cancellation token
}
async Task Test()
{
    await Task.Delay(10);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I wish to provide creation options here, ie LongRunning, and
>   possibly also a cancellation token

You can't customize `TaskCreationOptions` on the `Task` object returned by an `async` method. Essentially, it doesn't make sense: you don't create the initial `Task` here, `Task.Delay` does. You can think of it like this:

```
Task Test()
{
    var scheduler = SynchronizationContext.Current != null ?
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() :
        TaskScheduler.Current;

    return Task.Delay(10).ContinueWith((t) => { }, 
        CancellationToken.None,
        TaskContinuationOptions.None, scheduler);
}
```

Now, that's possible to control `TaskContinuationOptions` for the task returned by `ContinueWith` (including `TaskContinuationOptions.LongRunning`), but not `TaskCreationOptions`.

You can however provide a cancellation token:

```
async Task Test(CancellationToken token)
{
    await Task.Delay(10, token);
    // ...
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can't, and you don't need to. Neither of those options do what you think they do.

`LongRunning` is useless for `async` workloads; it would (in the current implementation) spin up a separate dedicated thread just to execute the first part of the `async` method (until the first `await` of an incomplete operation), and then resume the `async` method as regular work queued to the thread pool, ignoring that dedicated thread for the rest of the method.

Passing a `CancellationToken` to the task constructor is unnecessary; the only benefit it would get you in `async` code is that the code wouldn't start if the token is *already* canceled. And you can do the same thing by just checking it yourself before calling the `async` method. The proper way to handle cancellation with `async` methods is described in the [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx):

```
async Task TestAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  await Task.Delay(10, cancellationToken);
}
```